# SQL Server delete multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-delete

In SQL Server I have a table `CustomerAddr` and a column named `Stnumber`. I have non-integer values that I want to delete. I would like to delete the rows of the non-integer values. I use this query that shows the results of the non-integer values:

```
Select * 
From [CustomerAddr] [Stnumber] 
Where ISNUMERIC ([Stnumber]) = 0
```

I use this query:

```
Delete FROM CustomerAddr 
WHERE ISNUMERIC StNumber = '0';
```

Unfortunately `ISNumeric` is the culprit. I receive an error message:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'Stnumber'

If I remove `isnumeric` I can only delete one row at a time.. Help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

Before Deleting Confirms records using Select

```
select * From [CustomerAddr] Where ISNUMERIC ([Stnumber]) = 0
```

then use this

```
delete From [CustomerAddr] Where ISNUMERIC ([Stnumber]) = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

The where clause needs to be rewritten.

> WHERE ISNUMERIC StNumber = '0';

`ISNUMERIC` is a built-in function.  `StNumber` is a column that you are comparing to '0'.  These are not compatible.

You can write it like this:

```
WHERE ISNUMERIC (StNumber) <> 1;
```

If you meant non-number, then I would use the above.

But hold on!  The above will return rows that are not decimals, money data types etc.  The ISNUMERIC may not be what you want.  You say this:

> I would like to delete the rows of the non-integer values.

If it is an integer test, `ISNUMERIC` isn't right.  `ISNUMERIC will return a 1 (or a true)` for a value that could be a decimal.  A decimal is not an integer.

This may give you what you want if you meant integer:

```
WHERE StNumber NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, you can use the with clause

```
With TempAlias as (
   Select * From [CustomerAddr] [Stnumber] Where ISNUMERIC ([Stnumber]) = 0)
delete from TempAlias
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not equal to your delete; IsNumeric is a function that returns 0 or 1, based on whether its argument is numeric. That's what you do in your select query.

You need to put the parenthesis back in the delete command. Without it, you get an error, as you see.